# Determine rate of decay (calculus)

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

Question: A radioactive substance decays so that after $t$ years, the amount remaining, expressed as a percent of the original amount is $a(t) = 100(1.5)^{-t}$. Determine the rate of decay after $2$ years. Round to $2$ decimal places.

*For this question, I am unaware on how to do it and what formula to use. I was thinking on using the exponential decay formula: $P(t) = (P_0)(e^{-rt})$. The result that I got was $4.97\%$ but however I'm not sure if that's how you do it. Can someone please help me out?

Comment: "Rate of decay" refers to a rate - in this case the change in the amount of substance. Pretty much any time a rate is brought up (in calculus), it refers to the derivative of our function. What the rate of change of the substance at t = 2 years i.e. what is the derivative of P(t) when t = 2 years?

Comment: @JohnLathrop Oh, so would I find the derivative of the original equation and then plug in t = 2 and then I would solve? Thanks!

Comment: Yep. Note that you'll end up with a negative number as the answer, whereas the question asks for some "rate of decay" which will intuitively be a positive number - namely the absolute value of your negative answer.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding my comments into an answer:

The rate of decay will be the amount by which the substance $a$ is changing at some future time $t$, quantified as the time derivative of $a(t)$.

$$a(t) = 100*(1.5)^{-t}\rightarrow \frac{da}{dt}=a'(t) = 100*\ln(1.5)*(1.5)^{-t}*-1=-100\ln(1.5)*(1.5)^{-t}$$

So that
$$a'(2) = -100\ln(1.5)*(1.5)^{-2} = -18.02\%$$

Or in words, the rate of decay is $18.02\%$ per year.